# Is it entering same SAML session after POST request is made?

Tags: authentication, post, saml

There is a URL in which a SAML request is hidden. While making request, SAML authentication takes place. I would like to know if I will make the POST request to the hidden SAML URL with the same credentials as provided before. Will this session be the same as the one in which I have made the previous request.

PS: The machine, IPs and all are constant while making the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you open multiple tabs to access Google Docs, you would get multiple independent SAML sessions.

Each one would have different session ID and different Authentication Context.

For example, below are the two SAML responses with the same AWS IdP-init SSO SAML authentication flow.

```
<?xml
version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8"
standalone="no"?>
<saml2p:Response
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    Destination="https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
    ID="_c5b2e49b9abcb559d5784487a2a4b419"
    IssueInstant="2019-03-04T00:27:36.738Z"
    Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?
        idpid=<idp_id>
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode
            Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
        ID="_1ad7cff1e3c1000a8f112a1a43f35457"
        IssueInstant="2019-03-04T00:27:36.738Z"
        Version="2.0">
        <saml2:Issuer>https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?
          idpid=<idp_id>
        </saml2:Issuer>
```

```
<?xml
version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8"
standalone="no"?>
<saml2p:Response
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    Destination="https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
    ID="_1a68f45a31b8abfde9850907cd65c25b"
    IssueInstant="2019-03-04T00:28:27.362Z"
    Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?
        idpid=<idp_id>
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode
            Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
        ID="_f0b42fcf11de6279ffb1f890d50b57b2"
        IssueInstant="2019-03-04T00:28:27.362Z"
        Version="2.0">
        <saml2:Issuer>https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2?
            idpid=<idp_id>
        </saml2:Issuer>
```

As you can see the SAML Response ID is different between the two.

Comment: Thanks @chenrui for explaining this with example. I would like to know how can I capture the SAML Response using powershell/python. Using "Invoke-WebRequest" in powershell I am able to capture the request, but the authentication response is the key thing I want to capture. Do you have any suggestion to proceed for the same.

Comment: These are browser network trace involves with browser tab dancing, I think using the Chrome DevTools is the optimal solution. I am actually always using Chrome DevTools for debugging and it can export HAR traces too. Let me know if this helps. And please accept the answer. :)

Comment: I have used SAML DevTools extension in Chrome from time to time along with Fiddler. I can see the SAML response there but there extraction to be automated is what I am looking for. Btw I have accepted your answer. Thanks for the suggestions too. :)

Comment: Are you talking about the SAML response extract only for one browser session? I think you can export the HAR trace and do some work on that. Let me know if this helps. If you are talking about automated testing and parse the response, I dont know off my head. :)